# How to remove html tags from output but keeping the format

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-injection

I'm working with a MySQL database and to prevent SQL injections I used:

`$entities_correction = htmlspecialchars($Query, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');`

However when I try to show the information to the user I got this:

```
<p><strong>asdasdasdasdasd</strong></p><p><em>asdasdasdasd</em></p><ol><li><em>1</em></li><li><strong>2</strong><ol><li><strong>​asdasdasd</strong></li></ol></li></ol><p><strong>​​adasbui</strong></p>
```

With the tags and all that stuff. How can I remove those tags and make it look like this when showing to the user?

Expected output:

**asdasdasdasdasd**

*asdasdasdasd*

1. *1*
2. **2**

   1. **​asdasdasd**

**​​adasbui**

Comment: How are you showing the information to the user?

Comment: I'm using this:
<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($AsignacionTareas["TareaDescripcion"]) ?>

Comment: Print `$AsignacionTareas["TareaDescripcion"]` without `htmlspecialchars_decode` and show us what you get. Copy the results from source view, not the web page plz.

Comment: Look at this thread [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for how you should be preventing SQL injections, `htmlspecialchars` is a no, especially with just `ENT_COMPAT,`..

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` does not prevent SQL injection as it’s also not intended to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `html_entity_decode`

The html_entity_decode() function converts HTML entities to characters.

Please refer to the below links :
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_html_entity_decode.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention... I'm already using htmlspecialchars_decode but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` for this reason. Just pass the data to it.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php